# PHPunit mock - call a function in a returned mock

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm pretty new to phpunit and mocking, and I want to test a Listener in my symfony2 project, what is a kernel exception listener.

This is the class I want to test:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $code = $event->getException()->getCode();
    if($code == 403)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'message');
        $session->set('hardRedirect', $request->getUri());
    }
}
```

And first I just wanted to test, so nothing happens if the code is 404, this is the test I wrote:

```
public function testWrongStatusCode()
{
    $exceptionMock = $this->getMock('Exception')
                      ->expects($this->once())
                      ->method('getCode')
                      ->will($this->returnValue('404'));

    $eventMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent')
                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                      ->getMock();
    $eventMock->expects($this->once())
              ->method('getException')
              ->will($this->returnValue($exceptionMock));

//here call the listener
}
```

but PHPunit say, getCode function was never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use "chaining" as you've tried. The reason is that methods `getMock` and `will` return different objects. That's why you lose your real mock object. Try this instead:

```
$exceptionMock = $this->getMock('\Exception');
$exceptionMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getCode')
    ->will($this->returnValue('404'));
```

**Edit**

Ok. The problem is you cannot mock `getCode` method because it's `final` and it's impossible to mock `final` and `private` methods with PHPUnit.

My suggestion is: just prepare an exception object you want, and pass it as returned value to event mock:

```
$exception = new \Exception("", 404);
(...)
$eventMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getException')
    ->will($this->returnValue($exception));
```

Comment: Actually I tried this, before I posted and didn't work either, same error, Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times. I also var_exported the class of the $event->getException() and it was the Mock_Exception class.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. I will try not to forget this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I mock the getCode() function.  It actually gets called from the ResponseInterface::getStatusCode() function, so that is what you need to mock:

```
$guzzle->shouldReceive('get')
    ->once()
    ->with(
        $url
    )
    ->andThrows(new ClientException(
        "",
        Mockery::mock(RequestInterface::class),
        Mockery::mock(ResponseInterface::class, [
            'getStatusCode' => 404,
        ]),
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [mockery library](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) with PHPUnit, which is great tool and makes life easier.

```
$exceptionMock = \Mockery::mock('GetResponseForExceptionEvent');
$exceptionMock->shouldReceive('getException->getCode')->andReturn('404');
```

Check out documentation for more... and I hope you will love it.

Comment: It's part generally, in Symfony $this->getMock uses the mockery  And if you read the previous answer, you can't mock the general Exception, what the problem was here, or at least the getCode function.